# Connect two lists of lists by order of their index in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have two lists, list1 and list2 that I am looking to connect by index of the elements.  I am looking to get the output below.

I'm relatively new to python, and to programming so I'm not sure the correct definition of this.

**Example:**

```
list1 = [[a], [b], [c], [d]]

list2 = [[h], [i], [j], [k]]
```

**Expected Outcome:**

```
output = [[[a],[h]], [[b],[i]], [[c],[j]], [[d],[k]]]
```

Comment: `zip(list1, list2)` gives you an iterator over the pairs, as tuples, so `([a], [h])`, then `([b], [i])`, etc. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use a zip function:

```
list1 = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']]
list2 = [['h'], ['i'], ['j'], ['k']]

output = [[*v] for v in zip(list1, list2)]
print(output)
```

Prints:

```
[[['a'], ['h']], [['b'], ['i']], [['c'], ['j']], [['d'], ['k']]]
```